# DynamoDB ordering/sorting items with query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DDB Table which contains items with several attributes.
My partition key and sort key are both strings. I want to do a Query which needs both of these attributes, but I also need to sort data using a third attribute which is not included in the primary key.
Since DynamoDB only supports sorting with range key, is there any way to be able to achieve this with GSIs etc.

Comment: Not sure this is ideal, but you could always store a new, pre-calculated attribute which is effectively the composite primary key (compkey="${partitionkey}-${sortkey}") and then add a GSI whose partition key is compkey and whose sort key is the attribute that you want to sort on. When querying the GSI, compose the primary "${partitionkey}-${sortkey}" value.

Comment: Can you share the details of the attributes?  You sis they are strings,  but what do they represent?